# Android ListView with image view

Tags: android, android-layout

ok here is  it
when you create activity you link it to lay out in

```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

so you can change values on button ,EditBox and imageView

so lets say that we have layout called main2.xml
can you change only the view when the activity is pointing to main.xml

Answer (score 4):

Now also your question is not clear.

I think your intention is,
you have 2 xml layout files main1.xml and main2.xml. Initially you have layout main1.xml on android screen, correct ? Now you want to change the view to main2.xml, correct ??

If yes, use ViewFlipper. See the following sample, main layout file assume main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vf"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/main1" layout="@layout/main1" />
    <include android:id="@+id/main2" layout="@layout/main2" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Now `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
produce main1.xml as initial screen and if you want to change to main2.xml

use following code.

```
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.vf);
vf.setDisplayChild(1);
```

Even you are displaying main1.xml you can modify the views in main2.xml.

If you use setDisplayChild(child number), then only it will be displayed on screen.

Comment: Mr. [ghs.alshareef](http://stackoverflow.com/users/940155/ghs-alshareef), if you got answer to your question please share it and mark the answer also. You are welcome to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

I can''t understand what you are asking here, **removing ImageView.**

**We can use ImageView in ListView, by using custom adapter for ListView. We have to override the method getView() of BaseAdapter class, there we can add image resource to ImageView.**

I hope it will help you.

If you need more help see android tutorials or post code you written.

Bye.

Comment: ImageView img =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1Booking);
  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrive1);                                                     can i change image resource inside the list view because i want to change image in (R.layout.bookingdisplay_go) and the list Activity has been setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder_bookingdisplay); in diffrent layout

Comment: what you are saying is not clear. Creating confusion with different layouts, can you post sample code here? I will check it once.

Comment: Please post question clearly, don't make it confused or unclear, otherwise you won't get proper answer and will get negative votes, it leads to disabling your account from posting further questions. Ok.